# Scaling dataset A with parameters of dataset B

Tags: r, scale

I have a dataset that I've split into a training set and a testing set. This means when I feature scale them that I should scale data values to the training set, and then scale the testing set using the same scale. In particular, I only want to scale 2 of the columns of these two sets.

In Python I can do this using a scaling class - I just call `fit_transform` on the training set, then call just `transform` on the test set. But in R I'm not sure the simplest way to do this. I can scale the training set to itself using `training_set[, 2:3] = scale(training_set[, 2:3])` (since I want to scale just the second and third columns). But how could I scale the test set to this same scale?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I'm fresh to both R and Python and may be missing some terminology to find what I really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick version that is not as general as the solution of @JacobJacox would be

```
test_set[,2] = (test_set[,2] - mean(training_set[,2])) / sd(training_set[,2])
test_set[,3] = (test_set[,3] - mean(training_set[,3])) / sd(training_set[,3])
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.